# How to fix "Cannot resolve symbol" in a library module without flavors in Android Studio?

Tags: android

This is my project setup:

- I have 3 modules in an Android Studio project (app, feature & theme):

  [image: Android Studio modules]
- **Important:** Only **:app** & **:theme** modules have flavors. **:feature** module has no flavors.

  ```
  flavorDimensions("product")

  productFlavors {
      paid { }
      demo { }
      free { }
  }
  ```

  This makes Build Variants look this way:

  [image]
- This is the dependency graph:

  [image]

So:

- The **:app** module can see all the resources in **:theme** module because all Build Variants match
- Since the **:feature** module has no flavors, I have declared the **:theme** dependency this way:

  `implementation project(configuration: 'default', path: ':theme')`

  this makes the project to build successfully ✅ ✅ ✅
- However, the **:feature** module can't see resources defined in the **:theme** module.
- If I remove `configuration: 'default'` from the dependency declaration, I get this error:

  ```
  ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :theme.
  ```
- This is a layout file in the **:feature** module:

  [image]
- The `product_name` String is declared in the **:theme** module in different directories matching the flavor names

The question is:

How do I make the **:feature** module to recognize the resources declared in the **:theme** module without having to declare flavors in the **:feature** module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your error and managed to fix it by setting `missingDimensionStrategy` in the build file of your `theme` module:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    missingDimensionStrategy 'product', 'demo', 'free', 'paid'
}
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#resolve_matching_errors

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know.

Comment: I tried it and works well when the "demo" build variant is selected. But if I select "free" or "paid" I get a new error, see [here](https://i.imgur.com/EjLWE8h.png). Maybe this is a different problem.